# Cannot get Excel conditioning to work with AND and NOT statement

Tags: excel, formatting, formula

Trying to get Excel to format my *Due* column when the date in column has passed B has passed the date in B1 and the task is not marked as "complete" in column C

[image]

I wrote the following statement in the conditional formatting:

```
=IF(AND($B3>$B$1),NOT($C3="Complete"))
```

...but I am clearly missing something. Please help!

Comment: `=AND($B3>$B$1,NOT($C3="Complete"))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - THANK YOU SO MUCH! That worked! Incredibly grateful!!!